# JSON data returned with objects that have colons?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a returned json with this format:

```
items
   |___ [0]
         |____ media:group
                      |______media:thumbnail
                                  |_______ [0]
                                            |_____ url
```

I am trying to access the url value. I read somewhere that you can use a bracket notation like so: ['media:group'], but I'm still a bit confused on how to use this here.

I've tried doing:

```
var url = items[i].['media:group'].['media:thumbnail'][0].url;
```

My editor is giving me an error saying that a name is expected right after the dots.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks SO!

Comment: Can you post an example of the JSON returned?

Comment: you don't need the dots when using bracket notation: `items[i]['media:group']['media:thumbnail'][0].url`

Comment: If this really a JSON and not a JS object, you need to parse it first: `JSON.parse(json)`.

Comment: thanks for all the help everyone. @JAAulde I saw that thread actually and it didn't mention how to use it specifically. I was confused and ended up mixing the bracket and dot notation but it has since been answered :)

Comment: I'm not sure how much more specific an answer you needed, but I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, if your JSON is as I think it is:

```
var url = items[i]['media:group']['media:thumbnail'][0].url;
```

Try not to confuse the dot notation with the square bracket notation. Square brackets are a way of using characters that would otherwise be invalid with dot notation, but it's syntactically invalid to mix the two.

```
var obj = {property:'value'};
console.log(obj.property);     // Outputs 'value'
console.log(obj['property']);  // Outputs 'value'
console.log(obj.['property']); // Syntax error!
```

Comment: thanks Hexus, I'll mark this as the answer when time allows. That really clarifies it! :)